# JSF 2 resources with CDN?

Tags: jsf-2

As i understand it, the needs for JSF 2 resources is to help organizing resources directories, and add some versioning and localization.

But is it possible to combine this feature with a CDN ? I've never used CDN before, but it looks good, and would like to hear your ideas about it and possible combinations with JSF 2 resources, although i dont think it's likely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not possible  with `<h:outputScript>` and `<h:outputStylesheet>` yet, as they can only point to webapp's own resources, not to an external URL. This feature has already been requested to the JSF guys. See also [JSF spec issue 598](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-598). Right now it's scheduled for 2.2, but I don't expect it to be already implemented then as it's currently at 0 votes.

Until then, you'd need to specify them yourself using plain HTML `<link>` and `<script>` in `<h:head>`. You could make it a template definition if necessary, surely when you'd like to define them on a per-view basis.

```
<h:head>
    ...
    <ui:insert name="resources" />
</h:head>
```

and

```
<ui:define name="resources">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="http://.../foo.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../foo.js"></script>
</ui:define>
```

---

**Update** the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has since version 1.2 a [`CDNResourceHandler`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/resourcehandler/CDNResourceHandler.html) available which could be used to automatically replace JSF resources by CDN resources when running in production stage. See also [the `CDNResourceHandler` showcase page](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CDNResourceHandler).

Comment: You can bet on OmniFaces to bring the utils that community actually needs :)