# Acess JSF resource library from JS without ?ln=xxx

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2

There is a very good article on JSF resource libraries: [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415)

I'm implementing a simple JSF wrapper for a existing JS library. This library is referencing some images and provide a function *setImagePath*:

```
setImagePath("/test/javax.faces.resource/img/");
```

This is a first step to access the JSF resource library. Obviously I need a suffix like

```
.jsf?ln=xxx
```

to access the resource library. Unfortunately the JS library does not provide a *setImageSuffix*. If I modify the JS library and add this suffix manually to all images it works, but that's not a ideal solution.

Is there any to access my `xxx` resource library with *setImagePath* only?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem.  To do so you would have to extend your `ResourceHandler` to map your resources.

Fortunately, this was done after asking my question and added to `OmniFaces`.  So there is no real need for you to do so again.

By implementing an `UnmappedResourceHandler` you will then be able to map your resources without the appended suffix.

You will then be able to map your resources(images) in such a fashion :

```
setImagePath("/test/img/");
```

#### Links

- [UnmappedresourceHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/UnmappedResourceHandler)
- [Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963756/prevent-suffix-from-being-added-to-resources-when-page-loads)

*Thanks goes to BalusC and OmniFaces*