# UnmappedResourceHandler cannot convert URL in CSS to JSF 's valid URL

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, omnifaces, unmappedresourcehandler

Here is my setup:

- Web app 's folder structure and file names are exactly the same as the [UnmappedResourceHandler](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/resourcehandler/UnmappedResourceHandler.html) 's javadoc
- [UnmappedResourceHandler](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/resourcehandler/UnmappedResourceHandler.html)  is already registered in `faces-config.xml`
- `/javax.faces.resource/*` is already mapped to facesServlet in `web.xml`

The `style.css` is :

```
body {
    background: url("image/background.png");
}

body .test{
    background-image: url("#{resource['css:image/background.png']}");
}
```

Then I request `http://localhost:8080/app/javax.faces.resource/style.css?ln=css` and the respond is :

```
body {
    background: url("image/background.png");
}

body .test{
    background-image: url("/app/javax.faces.resource/image/background.png?ln=css");
}
```

I expect that all the relative URLs in CSS will be converted to the JSF 's valid URL like what `#{resource}` does such that I do not have to use `#{resource}` to refer to the relative URLs in CSS anymore  , but the `background`  's relative URL of the `body` selector still remains unchanged .

---

**Update to BalusC 's reply:**

1. If resource library is used , adding `?ln=libraryname` to all CSS images will work!
2. But if resource library is not used ,   `<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />` generates  `<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/app/javax.faces.resource/css/style.css.xhtml">`

   If I understand correctly from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963756/prevent-suffix-from-being-added-to-resources-when-page-loads) , using [UnmappedResourceHandler](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/resourcehandler/UnmappedResourceHandler.html) and mapping 
   `/javax.faces.resource/*`  to the `facesServlet` in `web.xml` should cause JSF generates the link of the `style.css` without `xhtml` extension.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `css` as a resource library as in:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
```

This is not right. It's just a folder:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
```

This will produce `/javax.faces.resource/css/style.css` URL instead of `/javax.faces.resource/style.css?ln=css`. You've otherwise to specify it in the image URL as well:

```
background: url("image/background.png?ln=css");
```

I will update the javadoc to clarify that more.

#### See also:

- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: Thanks BalusC! I tried your suggestions and still cannot get it work . Please see my update in the question . Thanks so much.

Comment: Did you deregister the `UnmappedResourceHandler`? The `<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />` shouldn't produce an URL with `.xhtml` extension. Do you have by chance any other `ResourceHandler` in your webapp which is possibly overruling the `UnmappedResourceHandler`? The `library` is unnecessary and only adds confusion and maintenance trouble (you've to specify `?ln=libraryname` in all CSS images). Just get rid of it.

Comment: I tried again if resource library is used , adding `?ln=libraryname` to all CSS images will work! So , the current problem is  if resource library is not used , `<h:outputStylesheet >` produces the URL with .xhtml extension . The `UnmappedResourceHandler` is already registered  and there are no other `ResourceHandler`  overrules it   as I specially  create this webapp from scratch in order to try `UnmappedResourceHandler`.

Comment: Btw  , according to the original feature request (https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=119)   , I originally thought that the purpose of `UnmappedResourceHandler` is to allow the URL in CSS to be defined as normal way and does not require any changes in order to suit JSF resource system. So , it seems I misunderstood it before as URL in css is still need to be changed by adding  `?ln=libraryname` when  resource library is used

Comment: JSF resource libraries are not part of standard HTML/CSS, so just omit it. The point is that you don't need to edit those 3rd party CSS files (Bootstrap, jQuery UI, etc). I can't reproduce your problem of `.xhtml` still being appended when referencing the CSS without resource library. Which JSF impl/version are you using?

Comment: Yes. This is exactly the purpose of `UnmappedResourceHandler` I thought before : is to allow  3rd party CSS files (Bootstrap, jQuery UI, etc) be used directly with `<h:outputStylesheet >` without any changes no matter resource libraries is used or not.   I am using myFaces 2.1.1 .Maybe I try to use `mojarra` to see if there are any differences.

Comment: Can't reproduce in MyFaces 2.1.11 (the current latest). Will try 2.1.1 later as I don't have it at hands now.

Comment: Oh . I have typo before .Sorry about that.  I am using MyFaces 2.1.11 .But I just try `mojarra 2.1.22 ` and it works . So funny.

Comment: Did you restart the server after making changes in Facelets file? When not set to development stage, MyFaces caches Facelets files very agressively.

Comment: Yes . I have already set to  development stage and the restart the server . I push my testing project into [this](https://github.com/kenchanmc/jsf-test2) .I would be grateful if you can test it when you are free.