# Can't loading CSS images in JSF

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

**Description :**
In my JSF application, I am setting the menu background images through CSS property.

I configured the file structure as follows

- This is my CSS code

**Style.css**

```
  #menu 
  {
   height:35px;
   width:950px;
   background:url(images/default.gif);
   /*background:url(#{resource['images:default.gif']}); 
   background:url(#{resource['images/default.gif']});
   */
  }
```

and this CSS file is under `/resources/css` directory, and
I am importing the css file in Facelets page using

```
<h:head>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
</h:head>
```

There is no problem in importing CSS file

**Problem description**

- I mapped the FacesServlet on *.xhtml:

  ```
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
  ```

  If I run the home page , the menu images which is configured in css is not loading
- When I remove the `FacesServlet` mapped configuration on `*.xhtml`
  the images are is loading perfectly

**i have tried**

I have tried the following methods in css file to load an image

1. `background:url(images/default.gif);`
2. `background:url(#{resource['images:default.gif']});`
3. `background:url(#{resource['images/default.gif']});`

But I couldn't find the solution yet.

**Updated Solution**

- Added Resource handler in `faces-config.xml`

  `<application><resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
  </application>`
- `FacesServlet` Configuration in `web.xml`

  ```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```
- Place images under `/resources/images` directory
- Image accessing format in  css file

  `#menu
  {background: url(images/bg.png)
  }`

Comment: how about `background:url("../resources/images/default.gif");`

Comment: Install Firefox. Install FireBug. Turn on FireBug. Go on your page and check the generated code. Is the .css really included? Could the file be found? Does your menu have the correct class? Is the image path correct? Was the image found? I'm sure you can narrow the problem down yourself with the correct tools...

Comment: @Daniel i tried as you said, still not loading , the  problem i found out in `web.xml` , configuring the facesServelet `.xhtml` mapping, if i remove that ,it work quitely.How can i achieve this..

Comment: @noone the problem not related to browser side,Ofcourse the images are in correct path as i mentioned above

Comment: @kark , here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15000857/617373 read it all... and check this out too http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/UnmappedResourceHandler

Comment: @Daniel i have configured the `resourceHandlers` in `faces-config.xml` as per your link showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/UnmappedResourceHandler..but i still still the `image` is loading ..

Comment: well it looked like it relevant, dunno, try the first solution in that answer, isn't the question there is exactly like your current one ?

Comment: @Daniel: The UnmappedResourceHandler by OmniFaces unfortunately doesn't support JSF libraries: > Note: the library is not supported by the UnmappedResourceHandler!
> this is a technical limitation, just exclusively use name

Comment: You can just treat the library as prefix folder in name. E.g. given a `<h:outputStylesheet library="some" name="style.css"/>`, just instead use `<h:outputStylesheet name="some/style.css" />`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [UnmappedResourceHandler by OmniFaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/UnmappedResourceHandler) to solve that

> This resource handler will produce unmapped URLs like /javax.faces.resource/css/style.css. This has the major advantage that the developer don't need the #{resource} EL expression anymore in order to properly reference relative URLs to images in CSS files.

Or take a look at the similar question/answer over here: [Prevent suffix from being added to resources when page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15000857/617373)