# Prevent icon conflict when using FontAwesome with PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, font-awesome, jsf-2.2, mojarra

I have a problem with menu icons in PrimeFaces : the UI icon seems to be in conflict with the FontAwesome one.
Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of icons in conflict]

When I look in my browser's inspector, I can see that four classes are applied to the `div`: `ui-menuitem-icon`, `ui-icon`, `fa` and `fa-terminal`.
Removing one or both of `ui-menuitem-icon` or `ui-icon` solves the problem. But, I would like to do it without some ugly script.

Here is how the `menubar` is displayed (please note that this line is in a layout (as a header)) :

```
<p:menubar model="#{menuGenerator.menu}" style="margin-bottom: 20px"></p:menubar>
```

My model is generated with the following method :

```
public MenuModel getMenu(){
    MenuModel result = new DefaultMenuModel();

    result.addElement(new DefaultMenuItem("SQL", "fa fa-terminal", "/"));

    //...

    result.generateUniqueIds();
    return result;
}
```

The parameter `primefaces.FONT_AWESOME` is set to `true`.

I'm currently using Primefaces 5.0, and Mojarra 2.2.12.

How do I make the menu appear without the conflict between the UI icon and the FontAwesome one (e.g. with only one of the two classes `ui-menuitem-icon`, `ui-icon` applied to the `div`)?

Comment: Are you using any theme?

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/21052851

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, I'm using the Bootstrap theme.
@BalusC Nice search, i wasn't able to find that using my keywords :) However it doesn't work... When I try to apply something different like `text-indent: 20px` its effect is applied to the `.fa` so the "^" is still present...