# Using FontAwesome 5.x with PrimeFaces 6.2+

Tags: primefaces, icons, font-awesome

I was checking this question:
[How to use Font Awesome from webjars.org with JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18891768/811293)
ant this question:
[FontAwesome with PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21052851/5113188)
with its answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33070133/5113188

Hi I want to use the new icons of https://fontawesome.com/changelog/latest **5.5** version

In my `pom.xml` file project...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/font-awesome -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

in my `web.xml` file

```
<!-- Fontawesome --> 
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>         
</context-param>
```

In my facelet .xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/templates/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:outputScript library="webjars" name="font-awesome/5.5.0/js/all.js"/>

...

    <p:spacer width="10"/>6
    <h:outputText styleClass="fas fas-map"/>7
    <h:outputText styleClass="fa fa-venus-mars fa-icon-custom" />
    <h:outputText styleClass="fa fa-female fa-icon-custom" />
    <h:outputText styleClass="fa fa-male fa-icon-custom" />
```

Note: I'm using `fas` and `fa`, but neither is working

Like shown my image all icons are failing

[image]

**How solve this?**

Comment: Start by removing the PrimeFaces related FontAwesome config from the web.xml, make an  example without a template and check the results

Comment: unfortunately is not working

Comment: Then remove it from the question, it is not related/relevant... and please make a [mcve]...

Comment: I put here in the question, because I following the another answer where it is used, And I was testing `primefaces.FONT_AWESOME` with `false` value.
Like in related questions, not all code is needed.

Comment: Code that is not needed should not be in the question. It can confuse people and have them spend time on irrelevant comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ability to use FontAwesome 5 was added in PF 6.2.12 and PF 6.3.  See this ticket and commit which adds the ability:

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4276

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/c28c0bccc615bffb99c30825c8c7d8084c3a72da

Turn default PF support OFF in web.xml:

```xml
<context-param>
     <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
     <param-value>false</param-value>         
</context-param>
```

Update your pom.xml.

```xml
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
     <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
     <version>5.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Use the proper WebJars CSS for JSF.

```xml
<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min-jsf.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="webjars" name="font-awesome/5.8.2/css/v4-shims.min-jsf.css" />
```

**NOTE:** You will have to change your "fa" as now Font Awesome has separated into different categories like"fas" "fab" etc.  Please see the [documentation here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use).

Comment: I thought I read somehwere (and hoped) PF was/is dropping the built-in support for FA and instead would suggest using the webjars solution

Comment: You are correct in future versions they are dropping it in support of WebJars but those styles were adding right now if people wanted to start using FA 5 in their projects.

Comment: This is just a useless comment to say that the solution above worked, since it has no feedback. I'm using primefaces 6.1 and FA 5 still worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing according to this answer, is not working for me.
I thought `name="font-awesome/VERSION_FONT_AWESOME/css/all.min-jsf.css"` must be according to declared in *pom.xml* `<artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>VERSION_FONT_AWESOME</version>`

Comment: When the *web.xml* is changed to `<param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>` all icon are not shown. but `<param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>` only old icons are shown!

Comment: When you uprgade to fontawesome 5.5 not all icons are "fa XXX" anymore some are now "fas XXX"  and FAR, FAL, FAB. See this page: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use

Comment: there's a open fork too: https://github.com/ForkAwesome/Fork-Awesome