# java ee resource names

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish, jsf-2.2

I have a java ee application running under glassfish 4, JSF 2.2 on windows7 x64.
And I have noticed that all my resources are served with an extra **.xhtml** extension.

for example:

```
/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css.xhtml
```

instead of

```
/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
```

Is there any way of removing the extra **.xhtml** extension?

The reason I want to do this is to avoid having to modify the paths in the all the external js and css libraries that I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [OmniFaces UnmappedResourceHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/UnmappedResourceHandler)

> This ResourceHandler implementation allows the developer to map JSF resources on an URL pattern of /javax.faces.resource/* (basically, the value of the ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER constant) without the need for an additional FacesServlet prefix or suffix URL pattern in the default produced resource URLs, such as /javax.faces.resource/faces/css/style.css or /javax.faces.resource/css/style.css.xhtml. This resource handler will produce unmapped URLs like /javax.faces.resource/css/style.css. This has the major advantage that the developer don't need the #{resource} EL expression anymore in order to properly reference relative URLs to images in CSS files.

Also , take a look at this [Prevent suffix from being added to resources when page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963756/prevent-suffix-from-being-added-to-resources-when-page-loads)

---

You also can point from one `js` to other `js`/`css` with the following approach:

Lets say you want to populate the `css` and `js` properties of some js object:

```
css:    $(document).find("link[href*='my-third-party-plugin']").attr("href"),
js:     $(document).find("script[src*='my-third-party-plugin']").attr("src")
```

Comment: There is a lot of image and font referencing from .css and .js files. Problem is because of the extra extension they cannot be found.

Comment: The only small change was: <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> instead of <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name> in web.xml