# Why does UnmappedResourceHandler require a servlet mapping for JSF resource URL prefix pattern?

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, omnifaces, unmappedresourcehandler

I was going through custom resource handlers in JSF 2 when I came across the [UnmappedResourceHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/UnmappedResourceHandler) of omnifaces. This was added in Omnifaces after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14963756/1055089) post.

I noticed that unlike the other two ResourceHandlers that Omnifaces provides viz. `CDNResourceHandler` and `CombinedResourceHandler`, this one requires and additional mapping for the JSF resource URL prefix pattern:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am no expert on JSF but I am curious to know why this is needed only for this type and not for the other two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF resources also need to be served by the `FacesServlet`. It's the one responsible for locating the right file in `/resources` folder and returing it along with proper caching headers. If you remove the `.xhtml` extension (or `/faces` path) from the resource URL, then the URL won't match the URL pattern of `FacesServlet` anymore and thus the `FacesServlet` wouldn't be invoked and wouldn't be able to do its job of serving the resource. You would only get a 404 Not Found error back, because the "raw" resource URLs do not match the public webcontent folder structure.

`UnmappedResourceHandler` makes use of the fact that JSF resource URLs have a common prefix path `/javax.faces.resource`, as identified by [`ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html#RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER). So, in order to invoke the `FacesServlet` anyway, even without the `.xhtml` extension (or `/faces` path), you just need to add the `/javax.faces.resource/*` URL pattern to the mapping.

The `CDNResourceHandler` doesn't need a change in the mapping as it doesn't produce JSF resource URLs anyway, but true CDN URLs like ones pointing to jQuery or Google CDN hosts. Those URLs wouldn't (need to) hit the `FacesServlet` anyway.

The `CombinedResourceHandler` just produces default JSF resource URLs, with `.xhtml` extension (or `/faces` path). It only uses a special `library` name of `omnifaces.combined`, so that the `CombinedResourceHandler` can identify them.