# Show more/less link if there is more text to be shown

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have this bit of javascript which works great for more/less:

```
function show(area) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(area)
    obj.style.display = (obj.style.display == 'inline') ? 'none' : 'inline'
};
```

and my HTML looks like this:

```
<p>some text</p>
<A href="javascript:show('hiddentext#{loop.index}');">more...</A>
<p class="hidden" id="hiddentext#{loop.index}">more text</p>
```

The problem is, I need to be able to hide the link if there isn't any text to show.  I'm using JSF and have multiple more/less links, but not all of them will have any more text to show.

I'm having an issue getting jQuery to work with my application (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206588/how-can-i-reference-jquery-src-url-in-jsf)), so jQuery solutions won't work.

Comment: where does the text come from, some server resource? if so then use `rendered` attribute of a `<h:commandLink>`

Comment: I couldn't get my javascript to work with `<h:commandLink>`.

Comment: `<h:commandLink onclick="myJSfunction()">` not working?

Comment: I can't use Primefaces

Comment: sorry brother, but you're doomed :-), ok so when there's no text -no link to show more, right? where does the text come from? is it hardcoded in xhtml?